# Using Excel 2013 VBA to build multipage report from userform selections

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel 2013 workbook that captures a lot of data about different equipment.  To make input user friendly, it is split in to two worksheets "Equipment" and "Equipment-Data".  Equipment is a front-end that presents the data from Equipment-Data in an easy to read/edit/print format.  Equipment-Data is the back-end data table with 85 columns of data by 100 pieces of equipment.

Navigation is performed by choosing equipment on a ListBox residing on a UserForm that lets them quickly navigate between items.  When the ListBox selection changes, the appropriate row from the data table is read to an array and written to the front-end. Any changes are seamlessly pushed back to the data table.  Excel was chosen over Access based on end-user familiarity and the fact the two worksheets are part of a larger workbook that wouldn't fit well in Access.  Also, the workbook supports one deliverable and isn't going to be updated long term.

I'm working on developing a way to gather all the equipment pages and export them to go into a report built from a mix of Word and PDFs (final output PDF). I'm sure there a dozen ways to do this but I'm wondering if there is a preferable way. I'm still relatively new to VBA-having already rewritten the code on this project to move subroutines from sheets to modules, pass variables between subs instead of using globals, and read/write arrays instead of looping through cells as I learned better ways to do things.

The way I see it, my options are:

1. Create temp worksheet, loop through listbox, copy range from front-end, paste special into temp sheet. I found from experimenting, I need to double paste-first xlPasteColumnWidths and then xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats.  I tried using just "Values & Source Formatting" (xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme) but I get an error about merged cells.  After the first iteration, I can replace xlPasteColumnWidths with just .Paste but still need to follow up with the Values & Number formats because there are equations.  After pasting, skip ahead ListIndex*78 to get to the start of next page and repeat. At the end, export the temp sheet to PDF and delete temp sheet.
2. Same as #1 but using CopyPicture method using xlPicture to get vector output. After loop, export to PDF and delete temp sheet. This *should* be indistinguishable in the final output from option #1 not sure if I'd run in to speed or memory issues with 100 pages of images.
3. Loop through listbox and use ExportAsFixedFormat to create a PDF using ListIndex&Equipment_Name as the filename. Then use an external PDF tool to merge the files in to one.
4. Create Access database, use Equipment-Data sheet as data source, and build report to mimic format of Equipment sheet.
5. Same as 1 or 2 but copy each ListItem to a new worksheet, select all the worksheets, export to pdf, delete worksheets.

Is there a better way that I'm missing?  I'm seeing options 1 and 3 as being the best to pursue. 3 seems like a good quick-fix since it is unlikely anyone else will need to build the report, but 1 would be nicer for some future user who might find the spreadsheet on a shared drive and want to reuse it on a different project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested options 1 and 2. Option 1 ran in about 30 seconds, using Save as..PDF (manually, haven't coded it yet) yielded a 2.3MB PDF (95 pages).  Option 2 ran in 100 seconds and produced a 1.0MB PDF. Both PDFs were similar, however option 2 showed a text box that was set to not print even though the xlPrinter appearance property of CopyPicture method was set. Saving the option 1 temp worksheet added 500KB to the xlsm file, option 2 added only 115KB which was surprising.

Code is below for anyone who might stumble on this in the future:

```
Sub PrintEqEst()
Dim tmpSht As Worksheet, EqSht As Worksheet
Dim i as Long
Dim TWB As Workbook
PrintingReport = True 'Global boolean used to keep display updating from being turned back on in event routine
Set TWB = ThisWorkbook
Set EqSht=TWB.Worksheets("Equipment")
Set cMyListBox2 = UserForm1.ListBox2
t(1) = timer *1000
If cMyListBox2.Rowsource = "" Then PopulateListBox
Set tmpSht = TWB.Sheets.Add(After:=TWB.Sheets(TWB.Sheets.Count))
Application.ScreenUpdating = False    
For i = 0 to cMyListBox2.ListCount - 2 '-1 because it ListIndex starts at 0, -1 because there is intentional blank item at end of List
   DoEvents
   cMyListBox2.ListIndex = i 'Triggers event that updates Equipment Sheet
   EqSht.Range("C2:L73").Copy
   If i = 0 Then tmpSht.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
    tmpsht.Cells(77*i+1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
    tmpsht.Cells(77*i+1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
Next i
tmpSht.UsedRange.RowHeight = 11.25
If ListBox2Index >= 1 Then cMyListBox2.ListIndex = ListBox2Index 'If something previously selected, go back to it. (ListBox2Index is global that keeps track of selected item)
With tmpSht.PageSetup
    [...]
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating=True
PrintingReport=False
Debug.Print "Create Report: " & Round(timer * 1000 - t(1), 0) & "ms"
End Sub
```

Option 2 uses the above code except the for loop uses:

```
EqSht.Range("C2:L73").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlPrinter, Format:=xlPicture
tmpSht.Cells(64 * i + 2, 1).Select
tmpSht.Paste
```

Answer (score 1):

I think option 1 would be the best. It gives you a lot of flexibility and if you structure your code in a good way, it will be quite easy to maintain as well. If you disable the screen updating while running, it'll be quite smooth for the end user.
Another possibility (since you mentioned Word) is the possibility to create a Word document from within your macro. Just add a reference to "Microsoft Word nn.n Object Library" under Tools - References. Then you have access to Word's object model and can create documents from your Excel data.

Comment: Option 1 runs pretty well in about 40 seconds.  I'll post the code in a little while.